# Ignore errors in SSDT Post-Deployment script

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I need to populate codelists after publishing my database using SSDT. So I've added new post-deployment script to the project and from it I call another scripts using SQLCMD :r command, each inserting data to one table. But if table is already filled, there are primary key constraints violated and whole setup is broken.

How can I suppress errors in post-deployment script? SQLCMD command `:on error ignore` is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you modify your script to avoid reinserting existing values? Using a common table expression, you would have something resembling:

```
;with cte as (select *, row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...) as Row from ... )
  insert into ...
    select ...
    from cte where not exists (...) and cte.Row = 1
```

Cannot be more explicit without having your table definition ...

Comment: Yes, it is one possible solution. But I'm looking for something more general, what can be used only in main post-deployment script.

Comment: I think it's the cleanest solution. Dropping the primary key constraint (via alter table ... drop constraint) without first cleaning-up the table (or dropping/recreating it) will possibly create duplicates (and will lead to errors when you'll try to re-establish the constraint via alter table ... add constraint ... primary key(...))

Comment: Even the response doesn't answer my question. It can help in similar situations. So I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good example of how to achieve what you're looking for using the MERGE statement instead of raw INSERTs.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/02/02/including-data-in-an-sql-server-database-project.aspx

Comment: However, be cautious with this method as the Table Values Function method only supports up to 1K records, thus a #temptable combination insert into #table, then Merge (with source from #temptable) type strategy. Just a heads up; I ran into that limitation.